# Laravel 5 Blade - where condition in count

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

withing my view I have access to a collection of FoodTypes.  I have cast it to an array to make it easier
to display

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:7 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "name" => "Frozen"
    "value" => "NOC M1"
  ]
  1 => array:7 [▼
    "id" => 2
    "name" => "Fresh"
    "value" => "NOC A1"
  ]
]
```

Initially, I had a Model for each individual FoodType e.g. Frozen and Fresh Models, but I soon discovered that
their tables/data were identical, so it seemed wrong to do this.  Now I have a generic Model, with the name defining
the type of food.

Anyways, when I had a Model for each type, it was simple to do a count on the number of particular types.  Now however,
I find myself doing something like this

```
count($data->foodTypes)
```

The problem is, I need to display the number for each individual type.  The above will return 2 because it does not take
the name into consideration.  So in essence, I need to do something like the following

```
count($data->foodTypes->where('name', '=', 'Frozen'))
```

Would something like this be possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use **where**.

The method signature from the base collection of eloquent collection:

```
public function where($key, $value, $strict = true);
```

That won't go to database again too.

```
$foods = \App\Foods::all();
$foods->where("food_type_id", 1)->count();
```

Comment: I need to actually do this within my view though, not the controller

Comment: So, send it to yours views somehow and do there. {{ $count }} or {{ $freshFoods->count() }} I don't know your view design or what data you need there.